# I am taking Selenium error

Tags: python, selenium

```
Using 1 seconds of delay
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "instaBrute.py", line 142, in <module>
    main()
  File "instaBrute.py", line 136, in main
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7f1aaba35110>> ignored
```

I am using Last Version of Kali Linux , and when I want to use program which using selenium , I take this error . So I try "pip uninstall selenium " - "pip install selenium " again , and nothing changes . Thanks for helps

Comment: Read the error message and make sure 'geckodriver' executable is in PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Choose appropriate version of the driver from [this page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), download and unarchive it, then place to the directory your script is located at.